# JavaScript: How do I return two values from a function and call those two variables in another function?

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, return

JavaScript:

```
                function getValue(){
                    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
                    var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;

                    return (num1, num2);
                }

                function add(){
                    getValue();

                    var result = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

                    return result;
                }
```

What I'm creating is a calculator that gets the values from input boxes. What I'm having trouble with is how am I supposed to call the variables I declare in the getValue(); function in my add(); function to create a value.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You can only return one value from a function. But you can of course have that one value be an array or an object that holds several values inside of it …

Comment: It will maybe help to study objects more in javascript.  One idea would be return an object like numbers.num1 = num1 numbers.num2 = num2 and then return "nmbrs".  You can also use numbers[0] =  num.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't return two values like this:

```
return (num1, num2);
```

Javascript doesn't work that way.  If you're trying to do a Python-like tuple, Javascript doesn't have a data structure with that syntax.

You can put two values in an array and return the array or two values in an object and return the object.

And, then when you call the function, you have to assign the result to something in order to use the returned result.

Here's one way returning an **array**:

```
function getValues(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
    // return array of two values
    return [num1, num2];
}

function add(){
   // get values and assign the returned array to a local variable named values
   var values = getValues();
   return parseFloat(values[0]) + parseFloat(values[1]);
}
```

Or, you could put both values into an **object** with named properties:

```
function getValues(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
    // return array of two values
    return {firstNum: num1, secondNum: num2};
}

function add(){
   // get values and assign the returned array to a local variable named values
   var values = getValues();
   return parseFloat(values.firstNum) + parseFloat(values.secondNum);
}
```

The object syntax is more descriptive and verbose because each property has a relevant name rather than just a numeric index, but it's also less compact.  In this particular case, you could use either the object or the array.

**ES6 Destructuring Update**

When returning two values in an array or an object, you can also use ES6 syntax to shorten the code to do that.  For example, when returning an object, you can use the shorthand syntax that assigns the property name as the same name as the variable as in:

```
return {num1, num2};
```

This actually returns an object that is like this:

```
{ num1: num1, num2: num2 }
```

And, then when you call that function, you can use destructuring to assign both values to variables:

```
function getValues(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
    // return array of two values
    return {num1, num2};
}

let {num1, num2} = getValues();
console.log(num1);
console.log(num2);
```

Or, you can use destructuring similarly with an array:

```
function getValues(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
    // return array of two values
    return [num1, num2];
}

let [num1, num2] = getValues();
console.log(num1);
console.log(num2);
```

Comment: You can now use object destructuring in ES6. Here's my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565814/4138919

Answer (score 2):

You can return an object and get its value in add function

```js
function getValue(){
  var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;

  return {num1: num1, num2: num2};
}

function add(){
  var obj = getValue();

  var result = parseFloat(obj.num1) + parseFloat(obj.num2);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply return an object! Objects are one of the things that make JavaScript so powerful.

```
function getValue() {
  return {
     firstNum:  document.getElementById("firstNum").value,
     secondNum: document.getElementById("secondNum").value
  };
}

function add() {
   var values = getValue();
   var result = parseFloat(values.firstNum) + parseFloat(values.secondNum);
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In ECMAScript 6 (ES6), you can use object destructuring, using braces to create and unpack objects (it looks like a tuple in your case). You can also make use of the property value shorthand available in ES6:

```
const getValues = () => {
  const num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
  const num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
  return { num1, num2 }; //note that this is the property value shorthand. 
  // It is a shorthand for { num1: num1, num2: num2 }
}

const add = () => {
  const { num1, num2 } = getValue(); //unpack using object destructuring
  return parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
}
```

More information here: http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/

Answer (score 1):

Try returning an array (*as you can only return one value from a function*)

```js
  function getValue() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;

    return [num1, num2];
  }

  function add() {
    var values = getValue(),
        result = parseFloat(values[0]) + parseFloat(values[1]);

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your variables into a neat little object, like so:

```
return {num1: num1, num2: num2};
```

Then:

```
var values = getValue();

var result = parseFloat(values.num1) + parseFloat(values.num2);
```

And so on..

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** need to return multiple values in your code.

```
           function getValue(ID){
                return document.getElementById(ID).value;
            }

            function add(){
                var result = parseFloat(getValue("firstNum")) + 
                             parseFloat(getValue("secondNum"));

                return result;
            }
```

The above code will fail if either of the IDs does not exist but so will yours.

Answer (score 1):

If those two returned values are going to be used by another function, then use them as parameters to the second function.

```
function getValue(){

    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;

    //return (num1, num2);
    //instead of returning the values, use them immediately to the consuming method
    var addedNumbers = add(num1, num2);
    return addedNumbers;
}

function add(num1, num2){

    var result = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

    return result;
}
```

Going back to your question, you cannot return two variables as a result of a function, unless you are returning it as Array.

Answer (score 0):

I think Javascript only supports multiple return values as global variables with destructuring, so its not recommended. However you can return an array and then destructur that array, its a bit of a inconvenience, however it does the same thing.

```
          // global multiple returns
     function getValues(){
           let values=[]; 
            values.push(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
           values.push(num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value);
          // return array of two values
          return [num1, num2]=values;
        }
         //recommended way without global variables requiring destructuring outside of function
            function getValue(){
                 let values=[];
                 values.push(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
                values.push(document.getElementById("secondNum").value);

                return values ;
            }

           let[num1,num2]=getValues();//breaks array into multiple variables

      function add(){
                getValue();

                var result = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

                return result;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to **assign multiple variable names** using a returned array, if you don't want to use indexing.  Here's how:

1. Write a function `foobar()` that returns an array: `return [foo, bar]`
2. assign the returned values to variables with `let [myFoo, myBar] = [foo, bar]`.
3. now you can use `myFoo` and `myBar` elsewhere in your code.

Result with your code.  (I'm using ECMAScript6 a.k.a. ES6 `const` rather than `var`.  You could also use `let`):

```
  function getValue(){
      const num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
      const num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;

      return [num1, num2];
  }

  function add(){
      const [num1, num2] = getValue();
      const result = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

      return result;
  }
```